# Serialize / Deserialize XML Derived From Treenode

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization, treenode

I have two classes, "company" derived from Treenode, and "document".

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Company")]
public class Company : TreeNode, IXmlSerializable
{
    private string _x;
    private string _y;

    public Company() { }

    [XmlElement("X")]
    public string X { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Y")]
    public string Y { get; set; }


    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }
    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        if (reader.MoveToContent() == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.LocalName == "Company")
        {
            x = reader["X"].ToString;
            y = reader["Y"].ToString;           
        }
    }
    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteElementString("X", this.X.ToString());
        writer.WriteElementString("Y", this.Y.ToString());
    }
}

public class Document
{
    private int _id;
    private string _name;
    private Company _company;

    public Document() { }

    [XmlElement("ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Company")]
    public Company Comp { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to serialize document, then save to file, its work. But when I deserialize, reader parameter always null. Any solutions ?

This is my code for deserialize. "sr" is variable that hold xml text.

```
var sr = new StreamReader(ms);
var myStr = sr.ReadToEnd();

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Document>));
using (TextReader tr = new StringReader(myStr))
{
    List<Document> docu = (List<Document>)serializer.Deserialize(tr);
}
```

I try to implement ISerialization and debug but never fired, and try to overide serialize and deserialize method, and no luck.

I am using .NET Framework 3.5

Comment: Have you checked your resulting XML?

Comment: @Fildor Yes, I have check. When deserialize, company data never fill.

Comment: Try to remove IXmlSerializable and the GetSchema, ReadXml and WriteXML methods in Company class. Then try again.

Comment: Oh and get rid of [XmlRoot("Company")] - there can only be one root!

Comment: Can you add your XML?

Comment: Got error "There was an error reflecting type 'CompanyNode'" if I remove IXmlSerializable and the GetSchema, ReadXml and WriteXML, [XmlRoot("Company")].

Comment: While serializing or deserializing?

Comment: both of them. This is the XML result from serialization http://pastebin.com/Wka3w8Zd

Comment: Doesn't look like an XML Representation of the classes you added in the question.

Comment: Yes, thats only for example. I think, the problem is because TreeNode implement ISerializable ?

Comment: That's totally possible, yes. Is it absolutely necessary for Company to implement TreeNode? Wouldn't it be possible to have a separate TreeNode-Child , let's say "CompanyTreeNode" that derives form TreeNode and has a Company as Field?

Comment: I think so. The application is 90%finish. If I change the class, I need to refactor all of my code :D

Comment: Hm ... yeah. Maybe my first idea wasn't that good, then. There must be another way around this. But RootElement Annotation was definitely wrong.

Comment: You are right .

Comment: Do you need to serialize any of the base class properties of `TreeNode`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43237/How-to-Implement-IXmlSerializable-Correctly), implementing `IXmlSerializable` correctly is in fact quite tricky.  Your implementation of `ReadXml()` appears to violate the requirement that it consume the wrapper element itself as well as all the contents, like so:

```
public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
{
    reader.MoveToContent();
    // Read attributes
    Boolean isEmptyElement = reader.IsEmptyElement; // (1)
    reader.ReadStartElement();
    if (!isEmptyElement) // (1)
    {
        // Read Child elements X and Y

        // Consume the end of the wrapper element
        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }
}
```

Furthermore, `reader["X"]` returns the value of the *XML attribute* named `"X"`, as explained in the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ksxd194.aspx).  In your `WriteXml()` you wrote the values of `X` and `Y` as nested *XML elements*.  This explains the `NullReferenceException`.  You need to fix your read and write methods to be consistent.

However, I'd suggest an alternative to implementing `IXmlSerializable`, which is to introduce a *surrogate type* for your `Company`.  First, [extract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3dyx26.aspx) all the non-`TreeNode` properties of `Company` into an interface:

```
public interface ICompany
{
    string X { get; set; }
    string Y { get; set; }
}

public class Company : TreeNode, ICompany
{
    public Company() { }

    public string X { get; set; }
    public string Y { get; set; }
}
```

This is optional but makes the code clearer.  Next, introduce a surrogate POCO that implements the same interface but does not inherit from `TreeNode`:

```
public class CompanySurrogate : ICompany
{
    public string X { get; set; }
    public string Y { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator CompanySurrogate(Company company)
    {
        if (company == null)
            return null;
        // For more complex types, use AutoMapper
        return new CompanySurrogate { X = company.X, Y = company.Y };
    }

    public static implicit operator Company(CompanySurrogate surrogate)
    {
        if (surrogate == null)
            return null;
        // For more complex types, use AutoMapper
        return new Company { X = surrogate.X, Y = surrogate.Y };
    }
}
```

Notice that the surrogate can be implicitly converted to your original `Company` type?  Now you can use the surrogate in XML serialization by setting the [`XmlElementAttribute.Type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.type(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute property to be that of the surrogate:

```
public class Document
{
    public Document() { }

    [XmlElement("ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Company", Type = typeof(CompanySurrogate))]
    public Company Comp { get; set; }
}
```

This avoids all possibilities of error in implementing `IXmlSerializable`.  Given the following input list:

```
var list = new List<Document>
{
    new Document { Name = "my name", ID = 101, Comp = new Company { X = "foo", Y = "bar", NodeFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10) } },
    new Document { Name = "2nd name", ID = 222, Comp = new Company { X = "tlon", Y = "ukbar" } },
};
```

The following XML can will be generated, and can be deserialized successfully:

```
<ArrayOfDocument xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Document>
        <ID>101</ID>
        <Name>my name</Name>
        <Company>
            <X>foo</X>
            <Y>bar</Y>
        </Company>
    </Document>
    <Document>
        <ID>222</ID>
        <Name>2nd name</Name>
        <Company>
            <X>tlon</X>
            <Y>ukbar</Y>
        </Company>
    </Document>
</ArrayOfDocument>
```

That being said, I don't really recommend this design.  Your UI should *present* your data model, it should not *be* your data model.  See for instance [How does one implement UI independent applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822334/how-does-one-implement-ui-independent-applications).  Replacing `Company` with `ICompany` whenever possible could be a first step to changing your design; you may find it becomes easier to replace your existing architecture with a `TreeNode` that looks like this:

```
public class CompanyNode : TreeNode
{
    public ICompany Company { get; set; }
}
```